# C2DM: Can I register for multiple sender-ids in the same app?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I have an app that manages a list of third-party servers and can poll them for information. These servers are supposed to be independent from each other (and potentially not under my control).

Now I want to implement c2dm notifications to avoid constant active polling.
The third-party servers will be able to publish their `senderId` and allow my client to send them the C2DM `registrationId` after registering with google.

**Now my question:** is it possible to register from the same application package for multiple c2dm senders? And if so, how would I distinguish the registration (and especially the unregistration) processes from each other, so that I can update the correct local server configuration entry?

The only resource I found was [this google groups thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-c2dm/browse_thread/thread/4cf9b6a402505041), but it hasn't been answered for a while. I hope you can help.

*Note:* This is only about the registration. When sending the messages, the third-party servers can inject their server name, so the message handler can distinguish them. But the registration process with google's servers doesn't seem to give me an option of passing back user defined information to my `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: If anyone is interested, I will now let the user (in advanced preferences) select a `senderId`. Doesn't really solve the problem, but at least the user is not bound to a specific server's private `senderId`. Of course now the client's registration request with the third-party server now has to include a `senderId`.

Comment: google support multiple senders in google-play-service
answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11910550/1083128

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be related:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-c2dm/browse_frm/thread/e2095d79c80de4c1/37325b1b1e5ec1e1?lnk=gst&q=multiple#37325b1b1e5ec1e1

Written by Costin Manolache  (Software Engineer at Google ):

> An app can't register 2 different sender IDs - there is a single
>   record for an (android-id + app id), the second registration will
>   replace the first one and the first sender won't be able to send.
>
> In any case - this is not a 'supported' feature right now, but sounds
>   reasonable.
>
> Please don't use one sender account shared with multiple customers -
>   besides TOS you may run into other problems.

I'm having the same problem.
A client has multiple accounts with multiple servers and shall register with all the servers it has accounts for to receive notifications.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your question, The description is like you wanted to get the Push notification from different servers which are Listed in you application and you can manage for that server for register and unregistered process.

If the above description is correct then :

You can maintain the list of the ServerId internally and generate the C2DM registration ID. coz the C2DM registration id is unique for the packages. it will be updated same packge tries to register again. so this registration id you can give to n number of server and they can send messages with this registration id and it will defiantly reach to your application.

For unregistration purpose you can always remove the server id from the list. you don't have to do much about C2DM registration id since it's only one. if you unregister from C2DM then application will not receive any messages from any of your server

Comment: The situation is: there are several unaffiliated servers that can each send push notifications, and the Android client should be able to register on each server independently to subscribe to its notifications.