# Can I receive GCM messages from two or more GCM SENDER_ID in my app?

Tags: android, push, google-cloud-messaging

I need to receive push notifications from different senders in my app. Will it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your question is *YES*!

According to GCM's official documentation your app can receive messages from multiple senders (limited to 100 different senders) and your intent code should look like the above one to work correctly.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(GCMConstants.INTENT_TO_GCM_REGISTRATION);
intent.setPackage(GSF_PACKAGE);
intent.putExtra(GCMConstants.EXTRA_APPLICATION_PENDING_INTENT,
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(), 0));
String senderIds = "968350041068,652183961211";
intent.putExtra(GCMConstants.EXTRA_SENDER, senderIds);
ontext.startService(intent);
```

Feel free to check official topic at GCM page about [multiple senders](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/adv.html#multi-senders).

Comment: Not sure what is this code exactly doing? Who is handling the service and how is the service going to to distinguish different SENDER_ID if they are part of the string

Answer (score 0):

Since you have api key and sender id, then it will work. You need to use API key given by google in your server(or servers) to send message to Devices.

Comment: Can I RECEIVE messages which was sended by different SENDER_ID. Of course I have register to receive messages from it id previously.

Comment: As far as I know, the sender id is for the mobile side of the application(Actually it is called project id that you created in google apis console). And when you want to send the message from server then you need to use same API key.

It works like that, you create an application in the google's api console then you get two different keys, project id and api key. You use project id in your mobile application and you use api key in your server application. One is for receiving the message(project id) and the one is for sending message. It doesn't matter how many senders are sending message.

Comment: I know how works GCM service. I already have project. I interested in receiving notifications not only from my project but from other one. Can my app receive messages from two differents projects?

Comment: I'm not sure that your application can register two different projects  (probably not)for receiving messages at the same time but you don't need to do this. Simply run the same code in server side but this time take two parameters, one for each project. Then you will be able to get the same message from two different project. Probably you cannot listen two different projects in your mobile application.

Comment: I develop library and I need to sent push to it. But may be situation, when programmer wants to receive notifications in his app too. In this case app will be need to register with two different projects in GCM service. I assume as you, that it is impossible. Thanks for answers.

Comment: Yeah I think so, it looks like impossible.